# Selenium when to use By id/name/class/spath/css, and page object

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I start to work with selenium webdriver v2, I have a few questions:

1. When to use By.id,By.name,By.className, By.cssSelector, By.xpath...?
2. Is it OK to combine all the By functions in the same test project?
3. When to use page object? Is it recommended to use for dynamic site?

Comment: please  mention ur search & reserch also update ur doubts.

Comment: Alex - still your question is not clear..please explain in detail what you have tried and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I tried all the By methods, i don't know what to use, i did know that not always there is an id, so i cant use By.id. Helping Hand- i want to achieve   consistency in my testing and order to achieve good test project ,NOTE:my question is in general and not for specific problem, my questions is intended to people with experience with selenium and what they recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should use the selector that are the easier to understand when reading your test (good for maintenance) and the more chances to be stable in time (good for maintenance as well). So usually, `id` and `name` are better than `cssSelector` and `xpath`.
2. It is OK to combine all the By functions in the same test project.
3. Page object is recommended when the volume of your test gets bigger and you want to reduce the amount of duplicated code. That works OK with any type of web site (static, dynamic)

Answer (score 0):

> When to use By.id,By.name,By.className, By.cssSelector, By.xpath...?

Better to use when its easier to read your code.
As XPath harder to read, you better to use something another selector.

example easy to read:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("password"))
```

example hard to read:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/div[5]/header/form/fieldset/input[1]"))
```

so in first example you can exactly say that this is password field, but you cannot in say this sure in second example.

> Is it OK to combine all the By functions in the same test project?

yes.

> When to use page object? Is it recommended to use for dynamic site?

You can use pageObject on most part of sites. But better on middle or big projects. Will be easier to maintain tests